# Testing nested, asynchronous Sidekiq jobs with rspec

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, mocking, sidekiq

Lets say I have the following base Ruby class:

```
class BaseWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
end
```

and the following two queues and one helper class:

```
class Finder
  class << self
    def find(id)
      AwesomeDBClass.find(id)
    end
  end
end

class Queue1 extend BaseWorker
  def perform(variable)
    if variable.some_attribute
      ...
    end
  end
end

class Queue2 extend BaseWorker
  def perform id
    local_variable = Finder.find(id)
    Queue1.perform_async(local_variable)
  end
end
```

And the following test harness:

```
let(:local_variable) do
   double(:local_var, some_attribute: true)
end

let(:local_variable2) do
  OpenStruct(some_attribute: true)
end

before do
  allow(Finder).to_receive(:find).and_return(:local_variable)
  ... code that triggers queue2 ...
  queue2.drain
  queue1.drain
end
```

This fails if local_variable (the double) is returned with:

```
  undefined method `some_attribute' for {"__expired"=>false, "name"=>"local_variable"}:Hash
```

And if local_variable2 (the openstruct) is returned with:

```
 undefined method `some_attribute' for {"table"=>{"some_attribute"=>true}}:Hash
```

interestingly, if inspecting either in queue2 (with a `puts` say) their values are correct.

Also, when reading the code for the two libraries:

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/ostruct.rb#L93

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/31baac3ace4ec0aff97d9e4e1928b06d18c685f8/lib/rspec/mocks/test_double.rb#L10

It seems that the state suggest that the constructor has run, but some other thing (`method_missing` binding, eg other method definitions on the class and/or `assign_stubs` running) has not happened. Any ideas as to how or why this is happening would be appreciated.

Comment: _Sidenote_: `Finder#find` is defined as instance method, but is called as class method.

Comment: good spot. That is also just a sanitization error from converting my code to a stackoverflow safe format. Editing now

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Use simple hashes instead of `OpenStruct` instances as params to `perform`.

`Sidekiq` [serializes](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib%2Fsidekiq%2Fworker.rb#L107) everything to `Redis`, please refer to [`Best Practices`](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#1-make-your-job-parameters-small-and-simple). `OpenStruct` is not a good candidate as a parameter to be passed to `perform`.

*Minor sidenote*: since [`Sidekiq` overrides `included` callback](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib%2Fsidekiq%2Fworker.rb#L26), it would be more idiomatic to:

```
class BaseWorker
  def self.extended base
    base.send :include, Sidekiq::Worker
  end
end
```